# Is it safe to install .Net 3.5 SP1 after .Net 4.0 RC has already been installed?

Tags: .net

I have a Build Agent that was only dealing in .Net 4.0 RC stuff, and so only had .Net 2.0 (natively) and 4.0 (manually) versions installed.

It now needs to support stuff compiled against 3.5 SP1.  Does anyone know if I'm asking for trouble trying to install 3.5 SP1 *after* 4.0 RC has already been installed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not so sure.  Watch what happens to c:\windows\system32\mscoree.dll.  If it is replaced then you'll have to re-installed 4.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the versions of the .NET framework can be installed safely side by side.  The only way you will get yourself into trouble is if you try to install different releases of the same framework version side by side (e.g. .NET 4 Beta 2 and .NET 4 RC 1 side by side).

Comment: I recommend dropping "No" off the start. It makes your answer appear opposite to what you're intending to express.

Answer (score 0):

It should be, yes.  .Net 3.5 runs as part of the 2.0 runtime environment.  The only thing that 3.5 adds are dlls.  This is combined with the fact that each runtime is separate from one another.

Comment: You may want to elaborate on what constitutes a runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, 3.5 will add some stuff to your 2.0, but it shouldnt break it, while 4.0 is a completely new "string" which means it can run side by side with the old series (2.0-3.5).